# winforms sort dataset

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset

is it possible to save the sort of a dataset ds into a XML file?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ds.ReadXml("file.xml");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];


        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
            dr["FN"] = textBox1.Text;
            dr["LN"] =  textBox2.Text;
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
            ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "FN asc";

            ds.WriteXml("file.xml");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#". That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0):

The [`DataView` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx) (which is exposed through the [`DefaultView` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.defaultview.aspx) on the [`DataTable` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9186hy08.aspx)) does not have a mechanism by which it can be serialized, and is not saved when the `DataTable` instance is saved.

That said, you are better off creating a structure that *is* serializable (using whichever serialization mechanism you choose) and have it serialize the `DataTable` along with the properties on the `DataView` instance exposed by the `DefaultView` property that are relevant to your application.

However, as [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9675309/50776) by [others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9675320/50776), you *can* convert the `DataView` exposed by the `DefaultView` property to a `DataTable` and save *that*.

Comment: No, but you can convert a view to a table and then serialize that.

Comment: @kprobst Updated answer with link to both of your answers.

Answer (score 0):

[Create a new DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8ycds2f.aspx) from your sorted `DataView`  and use it's [WriteXml-Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hyx9hb4.aspx).

```
ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "FN asc";
var sortedTable = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable();
sortedTable.WriteXml("file.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `DataTable.DefaultView.ToTable()` and then use the table's `WriteXml()` method. I believe the sort order will be maintained.